# Publish on Tumblr with an easy-to-type email

Tags: tumblr

I know Tumblr allows users to post on their blog by mail. But the email given by Tumblr is not really easy to type on a mobile phone, for example.

**Is there a way to post easily on Tumblr using a simple mail address, or a custom one?**

(I tried email redirection with Gmail, but Tumblr doesn't seem to understand it.)

My final idea? During a wedding, let everybody easily post pictures by emails on Tumblr.

Comment: What do you mean by tap? Do you mean type? Why don't you just add it as a contact and then use an alias for it?

Comment: Sorry i meant type indeed. The goal is to give this address to people so they can send pictures with  their phone.

What do you mean by an alias ? Create an account on a free email service like gmail, yahoo, or outlook, and then transfer each mail to tumblr ? Tumblr does not understand it.

Comment: I answered this question [over here](http://superuser.com/a/760386/327750).

Comment: You probably want to use a service that's better suited to something like this. Google Photos allows for "shared albums". So do Facebook and Flickr, if I recall.

Answer (score 1):

Can you create an account on a free email service like Gmail, Yahoo!, or Outlook, and then set this to automatically forward to the geeky address that Tumblr gives?

I recommend this approach for Blogger, because it's the only way that the blog-administrator can know who the emailed content actually came from. Not sure if Tumblr has the same issue.

Comment: You can't : If you set email forwarding to the tumblr address, the mail sent to tumblr will have wrong headers. eg :

Send mail from a@test.com to b@test.com, that forwards to gfdgfd1321@tumblr.com, this one will receive an email with headers :

From a@test.com, To b@test.com, and not :
From a@test.com, To gfdgfd1321@tumblr.com

Then, tumblr won't recognize this as "true" post mail.

Comment: I wonder if that's something which could be addressed in the settings of the free-email service, though?